# Wiki page question - Are all words indexed

Tags: search, wiki

When I create a wiki library site in sharepoint, do all of the words in all of the articles get indexed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ... We are using SharePoint 2013 and content from a wiki article is being indexed and shown within the search results of our Enterprise Search Center.

Hope that helps.